# Haskell: How to implement Data.Textual for algebraic (sum) datatypes

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am trying to implement a [Data.Textual](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-textual-0.3.0.2/docs/Data-Textual.html#g:2).Textual instance for an algebraic (sum) datatype.

I have two datatypes: `This` and `That`.  Each individually has their own instance of `Textual` from Data.Textual.  I would like to create an new algebraic data type, ThisOrThat, being

```
data ThisOrThat = DThis This | DThat That
```

and an associated instance of Data.Textual.Textual, that discriminates on the first character; that is, something like

```
instance Textual ThisOrThat where
  textual = if head t == '/'
            then DThis <$> textual
            else DThat <$> textual
```

But I have blatantly misused `textual` here, because I cannot see where to start with this one.

I did try cobbling something together using `fromString` to try to parse a value, but that fell flat, and I feel flailing around rather.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So I'm pleased to say, I worked this out for myself; for the benefit of others:

```
textual = try (DThis <$> textual) <|> DThat <$> textual
```

Seems to work nicely!